# How to merge list of nodes values into one array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with merging list of nodes values into one array. I would like to have one array of values and update it when buttons are clicked.

I used method forEach and then function where I nested Array.from() method.
I obtained a few arrays which amount is depended how many nodes I have.

html code:

```
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount" id = "amount0">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount" id = "amount1">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
```

and so on...

JS code:

```
function addAmount(el) {
  let amountElement, adjustAmount;

  if (el.classList.contains("add")) {
    adjustAmount = 1;
    amountElement = el.nextElementSibling;
  } else {
    adjustAmount = -1;
    amountElement = el.previousElementSibling;
  }

  if (amountElement.innerText >= 0) {
    amountElement.innerText =
      parseInt(amountElement.innerText) + adjustAmount;
  } else {
    amountElement.innerText = 0;
  }
}

function ordered() {
    const amount = document.querySelectorAll(".amount");
    amount.forEach(function(order) {
      let myArrays = Array.from(order.innerText);
      console.table(newArrays);
      console.log(order);
    });
  }
document.addEventListener("click", ordered);
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    addAmount(e.target);
  } else {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
  }
});
```

This code return in console two nodes

```
<span class="amount" id = "amount">0</span>
```

and two arrays:

```
["0"]
```

which updating. 
However if number of value is more than 10 the arrays start to divide number of tens and number of unities into two items in array, like:

```
["1","0"]
```

but I want to get one item ["10"].
Values of nodes are updating properly.

```js
function addAmount(el) {
  let amountElement, adjustAmount;

  if (el.classList.contains("add")) {
    adjustAmount = 1;
    amountElement = el.nextElementSibling;
  } else {
    adjustAmount = -1;
    amountElement = el.previousElementSibling;
  }

  if (amountElement.innerText >= 0) {
    amountElement.innerText =
      parseInt(amountElement.innerText) + adjustAmount;
  } else {
    amountElement.innerText = 0;
  }
}

function ordered() {
    const amount = document.querySelectorAll(".amount");
    amount.forEach(function(order) {
      let myArray = Array.from(order.innerText);
      console.log(myArray);
      console.log(order);
    });
  }
document.addEventListener("click", ordered);
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    addAmount(e.target);
  } else {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
  }
});
```

```html
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount" id = "amount0">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount" id = "amount0">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
```

Comment: can you make a snippet with your code? it is the menu with `<>`.

Comment: I try. Never done it before.

Answer (score 1):

Just push the values in a array and join them. Try like this

```js
function addAmount(el) {
  let amountElement, adjustAmount;

  if (el.classList.contains("add")) {
    adjustAmount = 1;
    amountElement = el.nextElementSibling;
  } else {
    adjustAmount = -1;
    amountElement = el.previousElementSibling;
  }

  if (amountElement.innerText >= 0) {
    amountElement.innerText =
      parseInt(amountElement.innerText) + adjustAmount;
  } else {
    amountElement.innerText = 0;
  }
}

function ordered() {
    const amount = document.querySelectorAll(".amount");
    var unit = [];
    amount.forEach(function(order) {
      let myArrays = Array.from(order.innerText);
      unit.push(myArrays);
      console.log(order);
    });
    console.log(unit.join(''));
  }

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    addAmount(e.target);
  } else {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
  }
});
document.addEventListener("click", ordered);
```

```html
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount" id = "amount0">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount" id = "amount1">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
```

Comment: It's not quite I ask for. The problem is when one value is reaching 10 it started to behave like an array get two items. I need to get one item with value 10.